# document.addeventlistener of javascript is not working for back button in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, button, back

In Chrome, when I first load a page with following code I get the console message

```
if (document.addEventListener){
    console.log("asf");
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', abc, false); 
} else if (document.attachEvent){
    console.log("as1f");
    document.attachEvent('onmousemove', abc);
}
```

but whenever i go / visit to next page with above codes too and press back button to revisit the page I do not get the console message.

Answer (score 0):

For what I understood from your question the code is showling message in console all the time I go back and forward on chrome. also it is notifying error for abc function as it is not in the code.

```
check the tested  [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gtbrh/).
```